# Remotely access OSX

Tags: mac-osx, remote-access

I have an offsite graphic designer that is having issues getting much work done because her 3Mbps Internet connection is too slow to work with large files.  If this was Windows, I'd just create a VM and let her use RDC to connect to it.  What do I do with Mac?  Past experience with VNC and the like haven't went well because complex graphics don't render well without a faster connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried creating a VM running OSX and letting her access the console? Easy with ESXi, just give her a URL.

Comment: In my experience, the performance of the console tab over a VPN connection is terrible (or is it my Windows 8 build of vSphere client?), it's probably the next best alternative to Apple Screen Sharing/VNC. Either way, I think this is a great opportunity for her to experience why 3Mbps just isn't reasonable.

Comment: The web-based console seems a lot better.

Comment: I have not tried that...I'll go do that now.  What's the URL you're referring to?

Comment: Carl there's two ways to manage and use an ESXi or vCenter server - via the Windows 'viclient' or via the web client. Sounds like you know about the former so to get to the latter you either just http://[servername] or https://[servername]:9443 if it's a vCenter box running SSO. Once you're in there you can select a VM and create a URL that you can give to a user that will, when launched, create a web-based window with the VM's screen in it, which you can then manage via the user's keyboard and mouse. You can even limit what they can and can't do with the VM that way too.

Comment: IIRC, you'll need to use a Mac as the server due to Apple's licensing agreements (OS X is allowed to be virtualized, but only on Apple hardware).

Comment: That's unfortunate as we don't have any Mac stuff sitting around.  I'll double check the licensing agreements and see what I find.  As for the web console, that looks to work pretty well; I may have a use for that in the future.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brian, I think that changed with vSphere 5.1 - happy to be wrong but I think you're ok now.

Comment: @Chopper, it looks like he's right.  http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005334

Answer (score 0):

> "If this was Windows, I'd just create a VM and let her use RDC to
>   connect to it."

And why can't she remote into a Windows VM/machine from a Mac?

There are really tons of way to help here, so I'm honestly not sure if this question should be closed as being "Too Broad", but:

- increase her bandwidth to handle her job
- let her Remote into a Terminal Server, VM, whatever in your network
- use something like Dropbox or similar to sync the files local to her and then back again after she's done editing

Comment: Has to be Mac/OSX...you know how developers are.  The bandwidth is fixed, so I can't do anything about that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you meant has to be a mac that she works off of regardless.  I get you now.